# How to use Django's models in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, django

I have an app in Django with 2 news in the data base. I'm using views.py in order to display these news in my html page.

**Models.py**

```
class News(models.Model):
    news_title     = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    news_body       = models.TextField(max_length=1500)
```

**Views.py**

```
def news(request):
    news_f = News.objects.all().order_by('-news_id') 
    news_f_html = serializers.serialize("json",News.objects.all())
    news_dic=  {'news_f':news_f,'ac_tab_n':'ac_tab', 'news_f_html':news_f_html}
    return render(request, 'news.html',news_dic)
```

I want to display the news' body using html tag but I can't because it's a string. I've been reading and I tried to serialize the news in order to use news_f_html in JavaScript.

**scripts.js**

```
var news = "{{ news_f_html }}";
```

But this doesn't work. I can't display, for example:

```
console.log(news[1].news_title) //Note that I have 2 news in my db app
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static files (js, css) know nothing about context of the page. You need to explicitly pass this context to your js code.
The [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) function returns an [HttpResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse), which is plain text by default, and only works with templates. That's it, Django only passes data to `news.html` template (and to the templates that are called in it like this `{% include "template.html"%}`), **but not static files**. If you want to pass data to a js file, then let your view return [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects), and let your js code fetch data by url.
Since you are just starting your journey in Django, then try to do in similar way:

In your `news.html` template write these lines (this is how you initialize the variables):

```js
{# news.html #}
...
<script>
  var news = {{ news_f_html }}; // note that this assignment without quotes - "{{ news_f_html }}" will be just string variable
</script>
...
```

And after these lines, import your js file with code that will process your context.
That's all, js-code got these variables from the template and can already work with them.

```js
{# news.html #}
...
<script>
  var news = {{ news_f_html|safe }}; // note that this assignment without quotes - "{{ news_f_html }}" will be just string variable
</script>
...

<script src="{% static 'path/to/your/js/code.js' %}"></script>
```

Since you are already using serializers (<s>I think this is DRF</s> see update), so in the future look towards the [Django Rest Framework views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/) to create an API.

**Update:**

So you're using [Django's core serializers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/serialization/).

In this case, for the desired result you need to change your view, for example, like this:

```py
def news(request):
    news_f = News.objects.all().order_by('-news_id') 
    news_f_html = []
    for instance in News.objects.all():  # it's not serialization, but extracting of the useful fields
        news_f_html.append({'pk': instance.pk, 'title': instance.news_title, 'body': instance.news_body})
    news_dic = {'news_f': news_f, 'ac_tab_n': 'ac_tab', 'news_f_html': news_f_html}
    return render(request, 'news.html', news_dic)
```

Comment: How can I access to the fields in the var news? When I use console.log, it return: `news is not defined`

Comment: @VicenteC I think your console was showing errors before this, because of bad parsing of variable. I updated answer. See ```var news = {{ news_f_html|safe }};``` ```|safe``` addition.

Comment: Also, your original code in ```views.py``` is valid (except that I don't see ```news_id``` field in your model). So my **Update** part is redundant for you.

Comment: I still have the error: ´news is not defined´. I have not problem using {{ var|safe}} in HTML but when I insert it in <script></script> it return that error

Comment: @VicenteC , please, provide your ```news.html``` code.